# Absolutely continuity of joint distribution of Brownian motion,its minimum and its maximum.

Tags: probability-distributions, brownian-motion

Let $W_u, 0\leq u \leq t$ be brownian motion.
Let $m_t= min_{0\leq u\leq t} W_u$ and $M_t = max_{0 \leq u \leq t} W_u$.

The fact that $(M_t , W_t)$ is absolutely continuous to Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is known in some stochastic calculus book.

By symmetry of Brownian motion, $(m_t,W_t)$ is absolutely continous to Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I want to know whether $(m_t, M_t , W_t)$ is absolutely continuous to Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @saz As cited in Schilling & Partzsch, the triple law gives only the density $P(m_t > a, M_t < b, B_t \in dx) $ as an infinite series for _fixed_ $a < 0 < b$. Does this show the desired absolute continuity?

Comment: @saz, I don't see how you find that $P((m_t,M_t,B_t) \in N \cap (a,\infty) \times (-\infty,b) \times \mathbb{R})=0$. I can see the set of $N$ such that $P((m_t,M_t,B_t) \in N \cap \cdot) = 0$ contains any set $A\times B \times N_3$ where $N_3$ is Lebesgue null and $A = (a,\infty), B = (\infty, b)$. It is also closed under subset (and hence intersection and relative complements), and countable union. Extending the argument to functions for which $\int f P(dm, dM, dW) = 0$ we find this set is a vector space containing indicators of the aforementioned sets. Does this somehow give the result?

Comment: @nullUser Right, it doesn't work the way I thought (... that's why I removed my comments). One approach would be to take Lévy's triple law for $P(m_t>a,M_t<b,B_t \in dx)$ and then to show differentiability with respect to $a$ and $b$. Not sure whether there is an easier approach. In any case, the joint law is absolutely continuous, see e.g. Handbook of Brownian motion, Table 1, Formula 28.8 [p.198].